# ionic textarea is giving a not null and not empty string when deleting it

Tags: javascript, textarea, ionic3

In my Ionic 3 project I'm checking if the string written on an `ion-textarea` is null or not.
If I do not write anything in the area, it tells me correctly that it is null, but if I write something and then delete it, it doesn't recognize it as null or empty, but if I try to print the value of course it prints an empty string.
This is a problem since it bypasses all the checks on the input I do still being empty.
This is the code I'm using, in html:

```
 <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="duration"  placeholder="Duration"></ion-textarea>
```

and in .ts file:

```
 if (this.duration==null || this.duration==''){ 
      console.log("Duration is empty")
    } else {
 console.log("Duration not empty")
}
```

Comment: tried `undefined`

Comment: If you want to check for `falsy values`, you can change like this, `if (!this.duration)`. **Note :** if condition will work for `this.duration = 0;` condition also.

Answer (score 0):

have you put this in .ts file? `duration: string = '';`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18360118)

Comment: sorry.i know right.i tried to comment but my reputation was insufficient